# How do I convert from dynamic object to specified Type?

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

Having a model of type `Dictionary<string,dynamic>` and would like to convert it to `Dictionary<string, MyType1>` or `Dictionary<string, MyOtherType>`!

I've tried

```
var converted = (Dictionary<string,MyType1>)model
```

without success tried

```
IConvertible iConv = model; var converted = iConv.ToType(typeof(MyOtherType), null);
```

too but it doesn't work

> **Exception**: Cannot convert system.object to type x

How do I convert from runtime type (dynamic) to a well known Type?

Comment: Looks like this is not a proper use of dynamic type. It is a static type.

Comment: Are _all_ values in the dictionary objects of type `MyType1`?

Comment: @DStanley that's it! after checking... it seems like the exception occurs when a key value is null!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in conversion from one dictionary type to another dictionary type. However, using [`Enumerable.ToDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548657(v=vs.100).aspx), you can easily create a new dictionary from any other data structure.

In your particular example, you can use it as

```
var converted = model.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => (MyType1) kv.Value);
```

Of course this will throw an exception if your values aren't actually of type `MyType1`. If they aren't, then instead of `(MyType1) kv.Value`, call some custom conversion function at that point.

Comment: Using "as" for casting coupled with "Where(i=>i.Value!=null)" should take care of exceptions. (unless non-nullable types are involved, that is)

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting an exception of type `System.InvalidCastException: cannot cast from object OF TYPE 'System.Object' to type 'MyType1'.`

Comment: @Bellash That's what I already covered in the last paragraph of my question: I'm only answering the question you asked. If you want to convert the values as well, there's not enough information in the question to tell how that conversion should work, only that you need to find some way of doing it.

Comment: thank you! you are write but I suggest you edit your answer so your code avoids exception... insert `as` as suggested by @Ptwr `var converted = model.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value as MyType1);`

Comment: @Bellash I prefer to leave it as a comment, if it's okay with you. Your question suggests that when the dictionary is converted, the new dictionary will have all the keys and values (possibly converted) of the original dictionary. In that case, the "fail fast" principle applies: an exception makes it easier to debug the problem if some value can't be converted. If you have values that you can't and don't want to convert, then sure, filtering makes sense. `model.Select(kv => new { kv.Key, Value = kv.Value as MyType1 }).Where(kv => kv.Value != null).ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value)`

Answer (score 2):

The following little demo works for simple types:
`MapDynamicToDictionary` test shows turning the dynamic to a dictionary.
`MapDictionaryToType` shows converting the dictionary to a type T.

You could improve on this by doing checks for types or using `as` etc.

```
public class Test
{
    [Fact]
    public void MapDynamicToDictionary()
    {
        dynamic d = new { Nr = 1, Name = "Devon" };
        var dictionary = TurnObjectIntoDictionary(d);

        Assert.Equal(2, dictionary.Keys.Count);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void MapDictionaryToType()
    {
        dynamic d = new { Nr = 1, Name = "Devon" };
        var dictionary = TurnObjectIntoDictionary(d);
        var instance = new MyType();
        Map(dictionary, instance);
        Assert.Equal(instance.Nr, 1);
        Assert.Equal(instance.Name, "Devon");
    }

    public static void Map<T>(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, T instance)
    {
        var attr = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
            foreach (var prop in instance.GetType().GetProperties(attr))
        {
            if (prop.CanWrite)
            {
                if(dictionary.ContainsKey(prop.Name))
                {
                    var v = Convert.ChangeType(dictionary[prop.Name], prop.PropertyType);
                    prop.SetValue(instance, v);                    }
            }
        }
    }

    public static IDictionary<string, object> TurnObjectIntoDictionary(object data)
    {
        var attr = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (var prop in data.GetType().GetProperties(attr))
        {
            if (prop.CanRead)
            {
                dict.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(data, null));
            }
        }
        return dict;
    }
}

class MyType
{
    public int Nr { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Could use `TypeConverter` to handle more complex examples. Nice example here: http://putridparrot.com/blog/type-conversions-in-c/

Comment: This is a brilliant solution! it looks good, upvoted while problem is solved by @hvd answer

Comment: Thanks! I added a conversion to the Map so it should succeed more often and a link to further possibilities at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I would put a static constructor on your well known type, which accepts `dynamic`, and build the well known type from that. e.g.

```
public class SomeType
{
    public static SomeType FromDynamic(dynamic arg)
    {
         return new SomeType
         {
              SomeProperty = arg.SomeProp
         }
    }

    public int SomeProperty {get; set; }
}
```

Then you'd just have to iterate over your `Dictionary<string,dynamic>` and build up the new object like:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, SomeType>();
foreach(var item in model)
{
    dictionary.Add(item.Key, SomeType.FromDynamic(item.Value));
}
```

Or borrowing from @hvd:

```
var converted = model.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => SomeType.FromDynamic(kv.Value));
```

Comment: Yep, that's one valid way of performing such a conversion. Personally, in this case, if the transformation is as straightforward as you suggest I would write it inline: `model.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => new SomeType { SomeProp = kv.Value.SomeProp });`. If the transformation is more complex, then I would go with a helper method like yours.